# Правки для страницы chekcout на wp+woo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На странице оформления заказа (checkout) создана форма "быстрого заказа" от плагина `contact form 7`. 
При этом основная форма при загрузке страницы получает `display:none`

Т.е. когда пользователь выбрал товары и перешел на страницу "оформление заказа" его  изначально встречает форма "быстрого заказа", а стандартная форма в это время скрыта. Если нажать на кнопку "стандартный заказ" - появляется стандартная форма оформления заказа, а уже форма "быстрого заказа" скрывается. (ну вот захотелось так заказчику)

Все бы ничего, но при нажатии в форме "быстрого заказа" кнопки "отправить" (кнопка идет от плагина, а не от стандартной формы) появляется надпись, что не заполнены поля "стандартного заказа" - т.е нет имени, города итп..

Вопрос: как сделать чтобы форма "быстрого заказа" отправляла данные без ошибок от стандартной формы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле: `/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js` вся работа по фронтен-еду для checkout-страницы. Скорее всего вам поможет вынести форму CF7 за пределы `form.checkout`

Comment: Да. Спс уже сам нашел решение. Когда цеплял форму внутри страницы checkout она была внутри общей формы этой страницы. Вынес за пределы и все получилось. За checkout.js отдельное спс)))